# Codeigniter: using a database to store database names for multiple users

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

Using Codeigniter 3.0.6

Until now I have been using the standard setup for Codeigniter. I have a database and all connects just fine. The question that I'm having trouble with is that I want to add a 'global_accounts' database, from which, depending on the user currently logged in will choose the database to load.

```
Global_Accounts
--------------------------------------------------------
user             | coolUser                    | user2
pass             | coolPassword                | passy
url              | coolestsite.mysite.com      | u2.mysite.com
database_name    | coolestsite_application_db  | u2_application_db
```

The application data/schema doesn't really matter as far as I'm concerned. What I want (and am going to set up, but outside of the scope for this question) is for when a user registers, they will fill out user, pass and url, and db_name will be automatically created. The script will then create a new database with that name, creating a blank copy of the application db for the user.

So for now, we're hard coding that, so we can assume that it's working perfectly.

What I want is inside Codeigniter's database.php file:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'mysite.com',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'database' => 'coolsite_application_db'
    ...etc
);
```

Instead of hard coding this file, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
$db['global'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'mysite.com',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'database' => 'global_accounts'
    ...
);

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'mysite.com',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'database' => $this->db['global']->get_db_name($loggedInUserId);
    ...etc
);
```

Hopefully that makes sense - I need to get the db name based on the logged in user. Obviously I need to build either a Model or just a function to grab it, but the question is where? Do I add a model, connect to the global db, and then load the model in the database config? Is there some other, easier, more productive way to do this, or is that it? Will the codeigniter core files be able to be called from inside the codeigniter config files?

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 database connections. 1 for the global user accounts and 1 for the actual user database. Then create a helper function to grab the user databases. Just an idea.

Comment: that is what i'm doing, but the problem is that I want it to automatically load the correct user database, depending on the user/url. adding a helper to the database.php (using get_instance()) causes infinite recursion.

Comment: change '$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;' into FALSE